# Product Catalog for Behavioral triggers - product links need to be individual links?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations, behavioral-triggers

We have been setting up Behavioral Triggers and following instruction.
We have created and uploaded file with all product but were wondering if it's going to work because we don't have individual links for individual products. Our file looks like this (just example not real data):

```
Product name      SKUID    Product Code   Product Link
Sport shoe red    SS001    123456         www.website.com/sportshoe
Sport shoe blue   SS001    789012         www.website.com/sportshoe
Sport shoe green  SS001    645378         www.website.com/sportshoe
```

So the product name, SKU ID and links are the same but product name and code are different.
Our website is set up that you enter the product site and there you have a javascript configurator that lets you choose color, size, etc - so we don't have individual links for each product.

How to best proceed in such scenario?
I read documentation but this is not mentioned.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement that items in your catalog have different product links. Your catalog file will work and all users will simply be sent to the same page.

Comment: Thank you for help @Eazy